# How do I install a color theme for IntelliJ IDEA 7.0.x

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

I prefer dark backgrounds for coding, and I've downloaded a jar file containing an IntelliJ IDEA color theme that has a dark background. How do I tell IntelliJ about it?

Comment: Where did you get the colour theme?? I've been looking for a good IntelliJ one.

Comment: I lost track of it, actually. There's an interesting looking one here (http://blog.gokhanozcan.com/2008/10/06/intellij-idea-dark-color-scheme/), though.

Comment: File -> Import Settings didn't work for me (but I only had a color scheme XML file.  I put the XML file in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIDEA10CE/colors/ and restarted the IDE.  Done.  The folder name in Preferences may not be exactly as mine is, but it should be rather obvious.

Comment: Hi @HankGay, it's probably worth updating the accepted answer on this question.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Go to File->Import Settings... and select the jar settings file

Update as of **IntelliJ 2020**:

Go to File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Import Settings...

Comment: I would for this being the current correct answer, as Intellij on import provides you with a selection window to where the import will be applied.

Comment: In IDEA 2020 `Import Settings` option is now placed in `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Import Settings...`

Answer (score 53):

**Step 1:** Do `File` -> `Import Settings...` and select the settings `jar` file

**Step 2:** Go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Colors and Fonts` to choose the theme you just installed.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look here: [Third Party Add-ons](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-third-party-tools.html)

You *may* have to extract the jar using a zip application. Hopefully inside you'll find a collection of XML files.

---

[IntelliJ IDEA Plugins](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea)

Comment: Hey, I think this link is broken. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Go to Settings => Plugins => Search Plugins in Marketplace

Search by `material theme` and download and restart it. it is a good theme.

In the market place, you can also search by `theme` and it will list all the themes and you can download any themes. You no need to find themes and download and import it. You can also remove the theme very easily. thanks

Comment: This is the only solution which worked, from all the others I got "not a valid scheme" or "the file contains no settings to import" errors.

Answer (score 9):

If you just have the `xml` file of the color scheme you can:

**Go to `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Color and Fonts` and use the `Import` button.**

[image]

Comment: This is the way you need to do it for now.

Answer (score 7):

Themes downloaded from **IntelliJ** can be installed as a Plugin.

**Follow these steps:**

```
Preferences -> Plugins -> GearIcon -> Install Plugin from disk -> Reset your IDE ->  Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme -> Select your theme.
```

Answer (score 5):

Interesting I never spent too much time adjusting the colours in IntelliJ although tried once.

See link below with an already defined colour scheme you can import.

[Where can I download IntelliJ IDEA 10 Color Schemes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414593/where-can-i-download-intellij-idea-10-color-schemes)

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1154

Download the jar file, file import the jar where you will see a what to import ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like nearly everyone else said, go to file -> Import Settings.

But if you don't see the "Import Settings" option under the file menu, you need to disable 2 plugins : IDE Settings Sync and Settings Repository

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find the .jar theme file in your disk. Drag the file into PhpStorm window and voila !

Comment: Does this procedure to enable dark mode on IntelliJ? Please respond