# Where can I download IntelliJ IDEA Color Schemes?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am an Eclipse user mainly and I find I must have a dark color scheme.

I cannot seem to find a dark color scheme as I search Google.

Where can I download IntelliJ IDEA Color Schemes? I am evaluating mainly for HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Very nice blog. And while I don't know if it makes you a better programmer, I'm definitely a member of the Dark Side. :-)

Comment: For those who want to check the posting click [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131003013636/http://aarongreenlee.com/share/coldfusion-builder-can-be-sexy)

Answer (score 509, accepted):

Since it is hard to find good themes for IntelliJ IDEA, I've created this site: https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes (note: site archived to GitHub repo) where there is a large collection of themes. There are 270 themes for now and the site is growing.

[image: Screenshot of the site]

P.S.: Help me and other people — do not forget to upvote when you download themes from this site!

Comment: @habitats I've been making some migrations, but now site is online.

Comment: I get an "Application Error" when I try going to that site.

Comment: Site is up again. It was the data corruption on the server. I've changed the hosting provider.

Comment: Man it is asking for $2 o.O

Comment: @haccks You still can download all the themes one-by-one for free. You know, I spent my time to I make that site and convert a lot of eclipse themes. After all, I have to pay for the hosting and domain. Do you think that $2 is very high price to support the project?

Comment: @Yarg; Of course not if I were not a student :). BTW, I tried to download one of the theme. It is downloaded in `.jar` format and I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @haccks You can follow instructions written on the "Help" page right there on the site.

Comment: Thanks. Got it where to place it. At least I can upvote :)

Comment: @haccks please contact me via email on the site

Comment: @Yarg; OK. Check your mailbox.

Comment: Wombat theme does not color static final fields like it shows in the preview. :(

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It is a shame idea people are not doing this

Comment: And... I'm still trying to find a working version of Darkside Contrast for phpstorm.

Comment: The dark themes I've tried from here look terrible on Python. The themes are incomplete.

Comment: @Yarg I've downloaded all the themes, but I wish there was a way to distinguish specifically themes that account for Java. There are many in there that does not account for Java development and only has like 3 colors across so many different things. I ended up using something called "Behave(Java Only)", which DOES account for some of the nuanced shit for Java. It was a lot of hassles. Wish you can implement tags to indicate which editor the theme is optimized for.

Comment: nice! would be good to include instructions on how to install it in the homepage, I think

Comment: Jeez, man, I've found that site through google and it's increadibly! Great job!

Answer (score 83):

If you're just looking for a dark color scheme for IntelliJ IDEA, this is the first link I get in a Google search:

**[Dark Pastels theme for IntelliJ IDEA](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803220905/http://tedwise.com/2009/02/26/dark-pastels-theme-for-intellij-idea/)**

[image: Dark Pastels theme for IntelliJ IDEA]

Of course, you can tweak either of these two schemes to your satisfaction. Don't feel like you have to stick to the fonts and the colors that the original authors have chosen. We programmers don't get nearly enough chances to try our hand at interior decorating to pass up this opportunity.

Is there any reason these won't work in the version you have? As best I can tell, you can simply import any theme that you want.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you.

Comment: @Zasz: Sorry, not sure what you want me to do. It isn't my personal blog, so I have no way of tracking down the contents. I removed the link, though, since you're right that it's dead.

Comment: BTW the http://tedwise.com/2009/02/26/dark-pastels-theme-for-intellij-idea/ link is active now. I could download the theme by following the link from it.

Answer (score 52):

The [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color theme (both light and dark versions) for IntelliJ IDEA is available [here](https://github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized).

[image: Solarized color theme for IntelliJ IDEA]

Answer (score 26):

I like ZenBurn theme, I think it is very mild and appealing for the eye. I had here my own theme's settings JAR file, but I stopped updating it. I still think that theme is very good so I updated this post to a suitable theme with similar colors which is already available on @Yarg's web site
[image: screenshot]

[Link towards the theme](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes)

Comment: the link is now dead

Comment: @nighthawk454: you are tottaly right, I stopped updating it - I rerouted the link towards Yarg's web site and updated the content of the post to avoid confusion

Answer (score 17):

Blue forrest makes for a very good dark theme, because it has appealing blues with yellows and greens mixed in. Highly recommended.

http://www.decodified.com/misc/2011/06/15/blueforest-a-dark-color-scheme-for-intellij-idea.html

Comment: Good tip. I like and use Solarized Dark in IDEA 10 on my Mac, but for some reason that theme looks terrible on my Linux machine. BlueForest looks fantastic!  Easy on the eyes.  Also-- most themes seem designed for Java/Ruby, but I work mainly in Scala these days, and this one was designed specifically for Scala.  I may even switch my Mac to this theme. Thanks!

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 16):

Please note there are two *very nice color schemes* by default in IDEA 10.

The one that is included is named **Railcasts**. It is included with the Ruby plugin (free official plugin, install via plugin manager).

[image: Railcasts IDEA 10 color scheme]

Comment: Actually (rather bizarrely), railscasts and the others aren't bundled by default: They're bundled with the Ruby plugin. A know a few people that install the plugin purely for the nice colorschemes. PyCharm now has a nice colorscheme called 'twilight': hopefully the Python plugin will soon include that too (it doesn't yet).

Comment: Ah thanks for the update! I have Rails plugin installed.

Comment: For the slow like me, its installed as a color/font option - not an Appearance option :)

Comment: These themes appear to be Ruby-specific. They look atrocious in Java/Groovy/Scala.

Answer (score 15):

I love the [Monokai Theme](https://darekkay.com/blog/monokai-theme-intellij/) (known from Sublime Text):

[image]

Comment: It does not look same with Sublime Text.

Answer (score 9):

This is just a suggestion, but what I like to do while I'm coding sometimes is to Invert the colors of my Screen. On a Mac it's Ctrl-Cmd-Alt->8 and it inverts the colors.

Haven't personally tried these in Idea10, but it worked on Idea9.
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1154

Comment: I find that inverting colors on the screen makes the edges of text have colorful artifacts, because the colors created by [sub-pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) are inverted too.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a theme I created which was inspired by GitHub's embedded source view.  I love how elegant their color scheme is, but lately I prefer a darker theme. This is theme is only for Java.  Sorry.  Download it here:  [GitHubInspiredDark.xml](https://docs.google.com/a/thedevel.com/file/d/0B_YrRp3w1ApYd3RfX1NOUFpvcEE)

[image: Inspired by GitHub]

Answer (score 4):

I made some improvements to the Darcula theme so it's a bit more usable for rubyists. You can find the repo and installation instructions [Here](https://github.com/jtmkrueger/darcula-improved).

Comment: The Darcula theme is damn good. I was searching for way to port it to Windows 7, but didn't found any solution.

Comment: As I know, it's included by default (at least for Java). Just find in the main menu: View -> Quick Switch Theme -> Switch look & feel -> Darcula

Answer (score 3):

Dark scheme for 
idea 10 - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26657232/dark_uptown.xml 
idea 11 - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26657232/dark_uptown_11.xml 
[Here](http://wash-inside-out.blogspot.com/2011/04/dark-color-scheme-for-jetbrains-idea.html) you can find out how it looks.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party but just wanted to mention that the [Jumpout II](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) theme really is amazing.. I have a lot of themes and this one really is great for a # of reasons..

1. it handles glare very well (yes even pure black on matte screens can produce glare, unfortunately my new matte monitor - has a more "glary" coating than my old one).. this is a grayish-black background
2. it has enough colors that you can easily see read even dense code - some themes that look nice at first use too much of one color and it makes dense code harder to digest
3. the comments are all gray, this is even better than dark green which is my 2nd favorite choice.. it really helps the code pop out..

so basically this is a great ***anti-glare, anti-dense-code theme***

### honorable mentions (I think these all can be found on that same site, although I'm not sure I spelled all of them correctly)

1. Dark Flash Builder (really great but at first the use of red can be confusing, but it is really one of its strengths. I had to modify it to make my error text highlighting different - I settled on some bright red underlined text)
2. Gedit Original Oblivion
3. Leone Dark II
4. Visual Studio 2013
5. Retta (very halloweeny)

#### and for white / beige / blue (in that order)

1. Oughsumm (wow best white ever, possibly the most legible theme I've ever seen - however, white is too bright for me in my current office situation, although occasionally I do switch to this when I want to quickly review a lot of code before a commit), also it is comfortably legible at 1 point smaller than all dark themes I've used.
2. humane-ist
3. rubyblue

p.s. please note I change the font of all the themes I use to Consolas 11 or 12 depending on the monitor. Consolas I find to be the best programming font out there. It looks great, easy to read and very well suited to LCD anti-aliasing. I tried so many programming fonts but I always come back to this one quickly. And it is not too narrow.. I'm not in the narrow camp, I believe narrow font aficionados don't program with ultra wide monitors - maybe program on a macbook or something just as bad :)

p.p.s I know solarized is supposed to be some kind of *ultimate, magical, life-enhancing nirvana-inducing theme* but I just don't get it.. I tried but failed to find it anything but annoying

Comment: and if you download Set-UI from the color schemes site all I can say is wow, this might be my new favourite, after some editing of it to my liking (dark with strong pop out colors )

Comment: ok, really it all depends on your lighting situation... Best if bright sunlight / bright light - if you want white, Oughsumm, if not Gedit Original Oblivion (it's a highly readable highly glare resistant grey bg theme)... best if darker room and glare is not a problem: Set-UI (vibrant colors on blackish background, yellow is a dominant color) ... also for bright work environment if you don't want white or grey, find yourself a nice blue background - it needs to be blue, not purplish or dark blue, those are prone to glare in the same way black is. Find a Borland-esque blue.