# What are the best IntelliJ IDEA Light Color schemes for java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[Where can I download IntelliJ IDEA 10 Color Schemes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414593/where-can-i-download-intellij-idea-10-color-schemes)
lists only Solarized light as a light color scheme.