# How to Use a Theme in JetBrains

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm

My eyeballs are bleeding from the brightness Is there any way to get a dark theme in JetBrains **(IntelliJ IDEA, PhpStorm,  WebStorm,  PyCharm, Android Studio)** that doesn't look bad or require hours of configuration?

I downloaded a theme but when I'm trying to import it into JetBrains I'm getting an error says

> "Import failed:
>   Theme it's not a valid scheme"

[image]

Current theme

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I was choosing the wrong Jar file it doesn't have a **Schemes Colors**

[image]

Here's the steps:

first of all go and choose your theme from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui)

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui

Then Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

You get the Preferences and the click on `Editor` and the click on `Color Scheme` and then `General` select the theme `Import Scheme.` **.Jar**

[image]

Then Select + press <kbd>⌘</kbd> to mark the themes you want to add

[image]

And here you go

[image]

> This theme Compatible with: IntelliJ IDEA  PhpStorm  WebStorm  PyCharm  RubyMine  AppCode  CLion  GoLand  DataGrip  Rider  MPS  Android Studio

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.  I tried downloading several themes which gave me the same error.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: error]

On a whim, I decided to drag and drop the downloaded color theme into the IntelliJ window.

[image: dialog]

Viola the theme installed!

[image: winning!]

Comment: That whim worked for me too. No restart even required. (PyCharm)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to install [Xcode-Dark Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13106-xcode-dark-theme) in Intellij Idea

I downloaded the jar file. it has contents as:

1. META-INF
2. Xcode-Dark.theme.json
3. Xcode-Dark.xml

In `settings` -> `Editor` -> `Color Scheme` -> `Import Scheme` -> `Intellij Idea color scheme(.icls) or settings(.jar)`

None of the above approach seems to work, I even tried drag & drop into. See the error.
[image]

Comment: Better use plugin --> install instead of this way
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57894293/1029110

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but this did:

In your downloaded .jar theme file, rename the *themes* directory to *colors*. 
 Re-import the .jar file in your IDE (Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Import Scheme) and it should import successfully.

Comment: I wanted to import Xcode-dark theme, and it does not have any theme dir. it has META-INF, ~theme~.json and ~themse~.xml. How to import that?